# How do I convert COUNTIFS formula to SUM(IF to avoid #VALUE due to external links

Tags: excel

I have an Excel formula which references several cells in other files, of the format:
=COUNTIFS('[FILE1.xlsx]Sheet 1'!$D$2:$D$5000,"A",'[FILE1.xlsx]Sheet 2'!$H$2:$H$5000,"B")

When I open this file, the cell value defaults to #VALUE (if FILE1.xlsx is closed).

Searching Microsoft Support (https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/260415) this is because formulas such as SUMIF, SUMIFS, COUNTIF, COUNTIFS or COUNTBLANK automatically calculate on spreadsheet opening.

Microsoft's workaround is to replace COUNTIF with SUM(IF(Range=Condition,1,0) entered as an array. (There is no example for COUNTIFS.)

**My question is: How do I change my formula to be of the format SUM(IF (AND?) ?**
(I do not want my formula trying to recalculate if I open the spreadsheet with the source file closed.)

I've tried =SUM(IF(AND('[FILE1.xlsx]Sheet 1'!$D$2:$D$5000="A",'[FILE1.xlsx]Sheet 2'!$H$2:$H$5000="B"),1,0)) (as an array)

But this returns 0.

Any thoughts?
(Or must I revert to a clunky 3rd column in my source spreadsheet containing the COUNTIF logic so my file can just use SUM instead ...?)

Comment: Axel has given you a good working answer, I think. Just FYI - your version doesn't work because AND returns a single result not the required array - you need to use * to "simulate" AND (as per Axel's suggestions) or use nested IFs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The array equivalent to your COUNTIFS would be:

```
{=SUM(IF(('[FILE1.xlsx]Sheet 1'!$D$2:$D$5000="A")*('[FILE1.xlsx]Sheet 2'!$H$2:$H$5000="B"),1,0))}
```

But

```
=SUMPRODUCT(('[FILE1.xlsx]Sheet 1'!$D$2:$D$5000="A")*('[FILE1.xlsx]Sheet 2'!$H$2:$H$5000="B"))
```

should also work.

Comment: Thanks Axel (& Barry!) - I can see now why '*' works - not seen that before so will explore this further with other problems.